Pytorch code running slow for Deep Q learning (Reinforcement Learning)
I'm a new student in reinforcement learning. Below is the code that I wrote for deep Q learning:
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
torch.set_default_device("cuda")
from collections import deque
import random
    
# Define the model
class Neural_Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.network = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_size, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128, output_size))
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.network(x)
    
# Define state to tensor
def state_to_tensor(state):
    return torch.as_tensor(state, dtype=torch.float32)

def optimize(optimizer, mini_batch, loss_function, gamma, target_net, online_net):
    current_q = []
    target_q = []
    for state, action, next_state, reward, terminated in mini_batch:
        if terminated:
            # episode over. Target q value should be set to the reward
            target = torch.tensor([reward]).clone().detach()
        else:
            # Calculate target q value
            with torch.no_grad():
                next_state_tensor = state_to_tensor(next_state)
                target = torch.tensor(
                reward + gamma * target_net(next_state_tensor).max() # Q learning
                ).clone().detach()
        # Get the current set of Q values
        current_state_tensor = state_to_tensor(state)
        currrent_q_values = online_net(current_state_tensor)
        current_q.append(currrent_q_values)
        # print('current_q_values', currrent_q_values)
        # Get the target set of Q values
        target_q_values = target_net(current_state_tensor)
        # print('target_q_values', target_q_values)
        target_q_values[action] = target
        target_q.append(target_q_values)
    # Compute loss for the minibatch
    loss = loss_function(torch.stack(current_q), torch.stack(target_q))
    # Optimize the model
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    # In-place gradient clipping
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_value_(online_net.parameters(), 100)
    optimizer.step()

def deep_Q_learning(env, gamma, alpha, epsilon, episodes, sync_rate, batch_size):    
    loss_function = nn.SmoothL1Loss() # Loss function
    num_actions = env.action_space.n # Number of discrete actions
    replay_buffer = deque(maxlen=20000) # For replay
    reward_buffer = deque([0], maxlen=100) # For last 100 rewards
    sample_observation = env.observation_space.sample() # Get a sample observation from continuous space

    # Create policy and q network
    online_qnet = Neural_Network(input_size=len(sample_observation), output_size=num_actions)
    target_qnet = Neural_Network(input_size=len(sample_observation), output_size=num_actions)
    target_qnet.load_state_dict(online_qnet.state_dict()) # Make the same weights and biases for both networks

    # Set the optimizer
    optimizer = optim.AdamW(online_qnet.parameters(), lr=alpha, amsgrad=True)

    # List to keep track of rewards collected per episode
    # rewards_per_episode = torch.zeros(episodes)
    
    # Track number of steps taken. Used for syncing policy
    total_steps = 0
    episode_rewards = 0 # total rewards of an episode

    for ep in range(episodes):
        S, _ = env.reset() # Initial state

        # Epsilon decay
        epsilon = max(epsilon - 1/episodes, 0.05)
        
        while True:
            # Epsilon greedy action selection
            if random.random() < epsilon:
                A = env.action_space.sample() # Take random action
                # print("random action", A)
            else:
                with torch.no_grad():
                    S_tensor = state_to_tensor(S)
                    A = online_qnet(S_tensor).argmax().item()
                    # print("greedy action", A)

            # Execute action, take step
            Sp, R, terminated, truncated, _ = env.step(A)

            # Running reward after taking action
            print("Reward, optimal action:", R, A)

            # Save it in memory
            replay_buffer.append((S,A,Sp,R,terminated))

            # Move to the next state
            S = Sp

            # Increment step counter and add reward
            total_steps += 1
            episode_rewards += R

            if terminated or truncated: # checking terminal
                reward_buffer.append(episode_rewards)
                episode_rewards = 0
                break

        # Check if enough experience or at least 1 reward has been collected
            if len(replay_buffer) > batch_size:
                mini_batch = random.sample(replay_buffer, batch_size)
                optimize(optimizer=optimizer, mini_batch=mini_batch, loss_function=loss_function, gamma=gamma, target_net=target_qnet, online_net=online_qnet)
                
                # Copy policy network to target network
                if total_steps > sync_rate:
                    target_qnet.load_state_dict(online_qnet.state_dict())
                    total_steps = 0
        if ep%1==0:
            avg_reward = sum(reward_buffer)/len(reward_buffer)
            print("Running episode:", ep, "Average reward:", avg_reward, end='\r')
    # Save policy
    torch.save(target_qnet.state_dict(), "frozen_lake_deepq_lunar.pt")
    # finished
    print("Training finished! Latest rewards: ", reward_buffer)
    return target_qnet

# Deep Q Learning
import gymnasium as gym
env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2", render_mode= 'human')
env.metadata['render_fps'] = 0
target_qnet = deep_Q_learning(env=env, gamma=0.99, alpha=0.001, epsilon=0.9, episodes=200, sync_rate=100, batch_size=128)
env.close()


The animation is running VERY SLOW while training. Also each step is very slow. I checked it by running the code both using torch.set_default_device("cuda") and torch.set_default_device("cpu"). Note that I have Pytorch installed properly and have Nvidia RTX 3060 GPU (torch.cuda.is_available() returns true). It is slow even if I ran everything in CPU. Please give me some suggestions on how can I make it faster?

Please edit your title to describe what the code does, not your concerns about it: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

is it fine now?

What I can do for you and give you some general suggestions:

Use library like Nuba or similar;
try Pypy is a JIT compiler;
if is possible use C or C++ modules.

and here the code with some improvements:
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
import random

# Define the model
class Neural_Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.network = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_size, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128, output_size))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.network(x)

# Define state to tensor
def state_to_tensor(state):
    return torch.from_numpy(np.array(state, dtype=np.float32))

def calculate_q_values(state, action, reward, next_state, terminated, gamma, target_net, online_net):
    if terminated:
        target = torch.tensor([reward]).clone().detach()
    else:
        with torch.no_grad():
            next_state_tensor = state_to_tensor(next_state)
            target = torch.tensor(reward + gamma * target_net(next_state_tensor).max()).clone().detach()

    current_state_tensor = state_to_tensor(state)
    current_q_values = online_net(current_state_tensor)
    target_q_values = target_net(current_state_tensor)
    target_q_values[action] = target

    return current_q_values, target_q_values

def optimize(optimizer, mini_batch, loss_function, gamma, target_net, online_net):
    current_q = []
    target_q = []
    for state, action, next_state, reward, terminated in mini_batch:
        current_q_values, target_q_values = calculate_q_values(state, action, reward, next_state, terminated, gamma, target_net, online_net)
        current_q.append(current_q_values)
        target_q.append(target_q_values)

    loss = loss_function(torch.stack(current_q), torch.stack(target_q))
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_value_(online_net.parameters(), 100)
    optimizer.step()

def deep_Q_learning(env, gamma, alpha, epsilon, episodes, sync_rate, batch_size):
    loss_function = nn.SmoothL1Loss()
    num_actions = env.action_space.n
    replay_buffer = deque(maxlen=20000)
    reward_buffer = deque([0], maxlen=100)
    sample_observation = env.observation_space.sample()

    online_qnet = Neural_Network(input_size=len(sample_observation), output_size=num_actions)
    target_qnet = Neural_Network(input_size=len(sample_observation), output_size=num_actions)
    target_qnet.load_state_dict(online_qnet.state_dict())

    optimizer = optim.AdamW(online_qnet.parameters(), lr=alpha, amsgrad=True)
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=100, gamma=0.1)

    total_steps = 0
    episode_rewards = 0

    for ep in range(episodes):
        S, _ = env.reset()
        epsilon = max(epsilon - 1/episodes, 0.05)

        while True:
            if random.random() < epsilon:
                A = env.action_space.sample()
            else:
                with torch.no_grad():
                    S_tensor = state_to_tensor(S)
                    A = online_qnet(S_tensor).argmax().item()

            Sp, R, terminated, truncated, _ = env.step(A)
            replay_buffer.append((S,A,Sp,R,terminated))
            S = Sp
            total_steps += 1
            episode_rewards += R

            if terminated or truncated:
                reward_buffer.append(episode_rewards)
                episode_rewards = 0
                break

            if len(replay_buffer) > batch_size:
                mini_batch = random.sample(replay_buffer, batch_size)
                optimize(optimizer=optimizer, mini_batch=mini_batch, loss_function=loss_function, gamma=gamma, target_net=target_qnet, online_net=online_qnet)

                if total_steps > sync_rate:
                    target_qnet.load_state_dict(online_qnet.state_dict())
                    total_steps = 0

        scheduler.step()

        if ep%1==0:
            avg_reward = sum(reward_buffer)/len(reward_buffer)
            print(f"Running episode: {ep}, Average reward: {avg_reward}", end='\r')

    torch.save(target_qnet.state_dict(), "frozen_lake_deepq_lunar.pt")
    print(f"Training finished! Latest rewards: {reward_buffer}")
    return target_qnet

import gymnasium as gym
env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2", render_mode= 'human')
env.metadata['render_fps'] = 0
target_qnet = deep_Q_learning(env=env, gamma=0.99, alpha=0.001, epsilon=0.9, episodes=200, sync_rate=100, batch_size=128)
env.close()

